# Zend Tool creation of a controller inside a module

Tags: zend-framework, zend-tool

I'm trying to create a controller inside a module using the Zend_Tool doing this:

```
$ zf create module admin
$ zf create controller login admin
```

With the first command it creates de module hierarchy, but in the second command it creates the controller and view into the default namespace.

Is it something that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

H.C.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

zf create module admin
    zf create controller login index-action-included[=1] admin

But i think you have to change the class name for the logincontroller manualy to admin_logincontroller.

Comment: I was getting frustrated as I was just trying `zf create controller login 1 admin` and getting an error `Unknown arguments left on the command line: api` - any better documentation on this tool than the sparse help?

Answer (score 8):

```
  zf create controller <controllername> 1 <modulename>

  zf create controller <controllername> -m <modulename>

  zf create controller <controllername> --module=<modulename>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have also command for **creating action** inside of module:

```
create action <actionname> <controller name> 1 <modulename>
```

(**1** stands for boolean that you want to create view script as well)

**Unfortunatelly you cannot create view inside of module!** :(

The command format for **creating view** is as follows (as of the version of ZF 1.11.6, I created new issue in Zend Framework issue tracker regarding it):

```
create view <controller name> <actionname>
```

as you can see **<modulename>** parameter is missing

but if you are able to edit PHP code and you are :) than you can simple edit your Zend Framework "**Zend\Tool\Project\Provider\View.php**" and

extend **line 95** into

```
public function create($controllerName, $actionNameOrSimpleName, $module = null)
```

and **line 105** into

```
$view = self::createResource($profile, $actionNameOrSimpleName, $controllerName, $module);
```

and that is it!

Now you can **create view inside of specified module**

```
create view <controller name> <actionname> <modulename>
```